# ErrorException in helpers.php line 531: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

this page works perfectly with few of rows in my database. but when I insert a lot of rows to database i get this error. thanks for any help and sorry for my bad English.
here is the error:

> ErrorException in helpers.php line 531: htmlentities() expects
> parameter 1 to be string, array given (View:
> /Volumes/data/Workspace/laravel/software_database_ihhp/resources/views/pages/filter.blade.php)

**PagesController**

```
public function filterKomoditi(Request $request){
        $kblicodes = Kblicode::groupBy('kblicode')->lists('kblicode', 'kblicode');

        // mengambil parameter
        $getkbli = $request->get('kbli');
        $gettahun = $request->get('tahun');
        $getnegara = $request->get('negara');
        $getpelabuhan = $request->get('pelabuhan');
        
        if($getkbli!=null){
            $hscode = Kblicode::where('kblicode', $getkbli)->get();
        }

        // fungsi select import where multiple hscode
        $condition = array();
            foreach ($hscode as $hs) {
                array_push($condition, $hs->hscode);
            }

        // fungsi filter
        if($gettahun != null && $getnegara != null && $getpelabuhan !=null){
            $imports = Import::whereIn('hscode', $condition)->whereIn('tahun', $gettahun)->whereIn('kode_negara', $getnegara)->whereIn('kode_pelabuhan', $getpelabuhan);
            $exports = Export::whereIn('hscode', $condition)->whereIn('tahun', $gettahun)->whereIn('kode_negara', $getnegara)->whereIn('kode_pelabuhan', $getpelabuhan);
        }elseif($gettahun != null && $getnegara == null && $getpelabuhan ==null){
            $imports = Import::whereIn('hscode', $condition)->whereIn('tahun', $gettahun);
            $exports = Export::whereIn('hscode', $condition)->whereIn('tahun', $gettahun);
        }elseif($gettahun == null && $getnegara != null && $getpelabuhan ==null){
            $imports = Import::whereIn('hscode', $condition)->whereIn('kode_negara', $getnegara);
            $exports = Export::whereIn('hscode', $condition)->whereIn('kode_negara', $getnegara);    
        }elseif($gettahun == null && $getnegara == null && $getpelabuhan !=null){
            $imports = Import::whereIn('hscode', $condition)->whereIn('kode_pelabuhan', $getpelabuhan);
            $exports = Export::whereIn('hscode', $condition)->whereIn('kode_pelabuhan', $getpelabuhan);
        }elseif($gettahun == null && $getnegara == null && $getpelabuhan ==null){
            $imports = Import::whereIn('hscode', $condition);
            $exports = Export::whereIn('hscode', $condition);    
        }elseif($gettahun != null && $getnegara != null && $getpelabuhan ==null){
            $imports = Import::whereIn('hscode', $condition)->whereIn('tahun', $gettahun)->whereIn('kode_negara', $getnegara);
            $exports = Export::whereIn('hscode', $condition)->whereIn('tahun', $gettahun)->whereIn('kode_negara', $getnegara);    
        }elseif($gettahun != null && $getnegara == null && $getpelabuhan !=null){
            $imports = Import::whereIn('hscode', $condition)->whereIn('tahun', $gettahun)->whereIn('kode_pelabuhan', $getpelabuhan);
            $exports = Export::whereIn('hscode', $condition)->whereIn('tahun', $gettahun)->whereIn('kode_pelabuhan', $getpelabuhan);    
        }elseif($gettahun == null && $getnegara != null && $getpelabuhan !=null){
            $imports = Import::whereIn('hscode', $condition)->whereIn('kode_negara', $getnegara)->whereIn('kode_pelabuhan', $getpelabuhan);
            $exports = Export::whereIn('hscode', $condition)->whereIn('kode_negara', $getnegara)->whereIn('kode_pelabuhan', $getpelabuhan);    
        }

        // fungsi select tahun negara, dan pelabuhan dari data Import
        $import_tahun_all = Import::whereIn('hscode', $condition)->groupBy('tahun')->get();
        $import_negara_all = Import::whereIn('hscode', $condition)->groupBy('nama_negara')->get();
        $import_pelabuhan_all = Import::whereIn('hscode', $condition)->groupBy('nama_pelabuhan')->get();

        // fungsi select tahun dan negara dari data export
        $export_tahun_all = Export::whereIn('hscode', $condition)->groupBy('tahun')->get();
        $export_negara_all = Export::whereIn('hscode', $condition)->groupBy('nama_negara')->get();
        $export_pelabuhan_all = Export::whereIn('hscode', $condition)->groupBy('nama_pelabuhan')->get();

        //tahun array
        $tahun_array = array();            
            foreach ($import_tahun_all as $import_tahun){
                if(!in_array($import_tahun->tahun, $tahun_array)){
                    array_push($tahun_array, $import_tahun->tahun);
                }
            }
            foreach ($export_tahun_all as $export_tahun){
                if(!in_array($export_tahun->tahun, $tahun_array)){
                    array_push($tahun_array, $export_tahun->tahun);
                }
            }
        sort($tahun_array);

        // negara array with key => value. 
          $negaraArray = [];
          foreach ($import_negara_all as $import_negara){
              if(!array_key_exists($import_negara->nama_negara, $negaraArray)){
                  $negaraArray = array_add($negaraArray, $import_negara->nama_negara, $import_negara->kode_negara);
              }
          }
          foreach ($export_negara_all as $export_negara){
              if(!array_key_exists($export_negara->nama_negara, $negaraArray)){
                  $negaraArray = array_add($negaraArray, $export_negara->nama_negara, $export_negara->kode_negara);
              }
          }
        ksort($negaraArray);

        // pelabuhanArray with key => value
        $pelabuhanArray = [];
        foreach ($import_pelabuhan_all as $import_pelabuhan){
              if(!array_key_exists($import_pelabuhan->nama_pelabuhan, $pelabuhanArray)){
                  $pelabuhanArray = array_add($pelabuhanArray, $import_pelabuhan->nama_pelabuhan, $import_pelabuhan->kode_pelabuhan);
              }
          }
          foreach ($export_pelabuhan_all as $export_pelabuhan){
              if(!array_key_exists($export_pelabuhan->nama_pelabuhan, $pelabuhanArray)){
                  $pelabuhanArray = array_add($pelabuhanArray, $export_pelabuhan->nama_pelabuhan, $export_pelabuhan->kode_pelabuhan);
              }
          }
          ksort($pelabuhanArray);


        // paginate
        $imports = $imports->paginate();
        $exports = $exports->paginate();

        // fungsi sum berat bersih dan nilai
        $neto_import = $imports->sum('berat_bersih');
        $value_import = $imports->sum('nilai');
        $neto_export = $exports->sum('berat_bersih');
        $value_export = $exports->sum('nilai');

        return view('pages.filter', compact('kblicodes', 'getkbli', 'imports', 'neto_import', 'value_import', 'import_tahun_all', 'import_negara_all', 'exports', 'export_tahun_all', 'export_negara_all', 'neto_export', 'value_export', 'tahun_array', 'negaraArray', 'pelabuhanArray', 'gettahun', 'getnegara','getpelabuhan')); 
}
```

Comment: SO is not a free debugging service, please narrow the error down and do some basic debugging yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is stating that you are providing an array of value `array(' BADARUDDIN (U)' => 'IDPLM')` on line `531` in `helpers.php`.

What more do you need to solve the problem?.

Comment: oh ya it should be `array('SM. BADARUDDIN (U)' => 'IDPLM')` why that can be `array(' BADARUDDIN (U)' => 'IDPLM')` ? i use array_add() to insert the data into array